# TSQL: Change the select result column order dynamically

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to change the result set column order dynamically?

A pseudo code example:

```
select [city], [state], [country] 
from mystuff
result order 2,1,3
```

so that the result set will be

```
state | city | country
California, LA, US
```

Comment: @user1939553 : I have added a query as answer try it that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the column order is determined by the SELECT list.  If there's a query that must be kept intact for some reason, you can use that as your derived table.  For example:

```
SELECT [city], [state], [country]
FROM (fixedquery) as X
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below, it will help you...

**Query :**

```
Declare @order as varchar(100), @Query varchar(1000), @Query2 varchar(1000)
set @order = 123

While len(@order) > 0
begin
      set @Query = IsNull(@Query,'') + 
                              case substring(@order, 1,1)
                                    when  1 then 'city' 
                                    when  2 then 'state'
                                    when  3 then 'country'
                              end + 
                              Case when len(@order) > 1 then ',' else '' end
      set @order = substring(@order, 2,len(@order))
end

set @Query2 = 'select ' + @Query + ' from mystuff'

Exec (@Query2)
```

**Output :**

```
If you give order as 123 then

City -- State -- Country as result    

If you give order as 213 then 

State -- City --Country as result

If you give order as 231 then

State -- Country -- City as result
```

Check it out...